# vb.net ideas on how to populate all text boxes and make them visible once a button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, coding-style

I was looking for some better way of coding to populate all text boxes and make them visible once a button is clicked, is there a better way of doing this than I describe below?

The scenario

I have a letter like format on a page with labels displaying address, name etc and it was recommended that on this page some of the information should be able to be edited. The idea I had was to keep the labels displaying the information but then when the edit details button is clicked the labels disappear, text boxes will appear and be populated with the same text as the label to allow the user to edit the details.

I seem to repeating lines of code but changing one thing each time

on page load

```
Dim Sname As String = Request.QueryString("Name")
lblStuName.Text = Sname
tbStuName.Text = Sname
tbStuName.visible=false

Dim Saddress As String = Request.QueryString("Address")
lblAddress.Text = Saddress
tbAddress.Text = Saddress
tbAddress.visible = false
```

etc...

on edit button

```
tbStuName.visible=true
tbAddress.visible = true
```

etc..

on the save button

```
 sqlStatement = "UPDATE StuTable SET Name = '" & lblStuName.Text & "', Address = '" & lblAddress.Text
```

My code seems very repetitive in many parts, I was looking for a better coding style to do this can anyone suggest a better way to do it? Is my idea sound right way to do this or can anyone suggest a better way it can be implemented?

Thank you

Comment: Is that a bug in the update sql, using the Text from the labels and not the textbox?

Comment: @jon I made a mistake when I was typing the code, but you are correct it should be an update from the textbox rather than the label

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered activating the inputs on the client-side? You could use a jquery plugin such as this
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

You'd still have to do some setup in your VB though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, no I have not considered this, is there anything more basic you can recommend? I don't have much experience coding in vb.net and the jquery plugin looks very difficult. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could code a method to do the dirty work and then just call it. You could even have a list of the textboxes:

```
Private _txtBoxes as Generic.List(Of TextBox)
Private Sub DoSetup(value as string, txt as TextBox, lbl as Label)
  txt.Text = value
  lbl.Text = value
  txt.Visible = false
  _txtBoxes.Add(txt)
End Sub
```

Call (on page load):

```
DoSetup(Request.Querystring("Name"),txtStuName,lblStuName)
DoSetup(Request.Querystring("Address"),txtAddress,lblAddress)
```

Setting to visible (on edit button):

```
For Each txt as TextBox in _txtBoxes
   txt.Visible = True
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this seems like something I would be looking to do. in the sub DoSetup, i am having some problem understanding those parameter you are passing, value as string - you say txt.Text = value do I have to set the value here? or is it right in thinking the value is assigned in the query string below it? can you explain the for loop? i am sorry if i am asking very basic questions, but thank you for your help

Comment: txt and lbl are parameters to DoSetup - you are actually passing a reference to the textbox and label that you want to configure into the sub. That means you can handle configuring lots of different controls with the same method. The for loop runs through each of the textboxes I added to the _txtBoxes list and sets them to visible, you'd use this instead of setting them to visible one-by-one

Comment: thank you for explaining this, I will give this a go and get back to you but it most definitely sounds like a better of doing things than I currently have coded it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative strategy would be to use javascript in the webform to switch the controls over:

In page  section:

```
<script lang="javascript">
   function DoEditClick() {
      document.getElementById("txtStuName").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("lblStuName").style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("txtAddress").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("lblAddress").style.visibility = "hidden";
      ...
   }
</script>
```

The markup for the edit button would look something like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnEdit" text="Edit" OnClientClick="DoEditClick()"/>
```

Comment: what is document? is getElementById the equivalent to a querystring i.e. get the value of the field from prev page. Do you mean the above code would replace the DoSetup sub and For loop in your first strategy? thanks

Comment: In javascript in a webpage, document represents the page itself, and getElementById finds controls within that page based on the ID you supply. The benefit of using javascript to switch to the edit controls is that you don't have the round trip to the webserver from the client. If you use event in the code behind to do the change then the edit button has to post back and the webserver has to process the request. With the javascript the client browser makes the change to the visiblity of the controls itself.

Comment: to get around that could it just be all put into an update panel?

Comment: That'll will still result in the round trip as its still the webserver doing the processing, its more optimal as not all the page gets sent back in the response though.